# "ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer" In prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to make a classifier of voices, mine and others and then apply it to a future program. I used the CNN model for this, in training it gave very good results, I converted the audio to a spectrogram for CNN to understand.
The problem is in the prediction, I do the same of converting the audio to a spectrogram but it gives me this error.

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 129, 1071, 1), found shape=(None, 1071)
```

While in the model I put this and gave no error

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(129, 1071, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

This is my code for the prediction

```
### VOICE CLASSIFICATION ###
voice_model = load_model(os.path.abspath('Models/voiceclassify2.model'))
classes = ['Other', 'Bernardo']

sample = os.path.abspath('Voiceclassification/Data/me/5.wav')
samplerate, data = wavfile.read(str(sample))

# convert into spectogram
frecuencies, times, spectogram = signal.spectrogram(data, samplerate)


vc_prediction = voice_model.predict(spectogram)[0]
idx = np.argmax(vc_prediction)
label = classes[idx]

print(label, " | ", vc_prediction[idx]*100, "%")
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

After some fiddling this was the solution:
On the one hand there was an error with the final dimension of the input (the `1` in the the input_shape). This represents the number of channels (think of RGB channels in an image). To expand our spectrogram we can use either

`spectrogram = spectrogram.reshape(spectrogram.shape + (1,))` or

`spectrogram = np.expand_dims(spectrogram, -1)`.

At this point the shape of spectrogram would be (129, 1071, 1).

On the other hand during inference the first dimension (129) was removed, because TensorFlow would interpret it as the batch dimension. You can solve this by wrapping the spectrogram in a (one element) NumPy array like this:

```
spectrogram = np.array([spectrogram])
```

Now spectrogram's shape is (1, 129, 1071, 1) which is exactly what we need.

---

Original:

This is definitely more of a comment than an answer but I cannot write those due to a lack in reputation, so feel free to move it to comments...

So the problem is that the expected shape (and thus the architecture of your network) and your data's shape don't match.
I guess that's because the predict() call expects you to hand over a batch (look at the first dimension of each shape) of samples to evaluate.
You may get around this by wrapping the spectrogram argument inside the predict call with a list: `vc_prediction = voice_model.predict([spectogram])[0]`.
If this doesn't do the trick I'd recommend to further investigate the shapes of training and evaluation data, I like to do this during runtime in debug mode.

Comment: it doesn't work with [spectogram], but I'm gonna try the second option. I will let you know:)

Comment: When I print spectogram.shape I got (129, 1071)

Comment: What's the final dimension (1) in your input layer supposed to do?

Comment: the one solve one problem I have when training the model, I don't know but it works with a one

Comment: I think getting rid of that dimension might do the trick... using [spectrogram] encapsulates your sample in another dimension for the batch (the "None" dimension at the beginning of the shape) making your input of shape (1, 129, 1071)... This would be the same as the input layers dimension when removing the 1... the shape of your training data might make it a requirement to add that final dimension, which you definitely dont need (as it's 1 anyways...) so I suggest you reformat your training data to be able to change your input layers input_shape to (129, 1071) and then it should work...

Comment: yes, but when I do that, I get this error "ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 129, 1071)"

Comment: I see... the 1 is the channel size of your "image" (like R, G and B are 3 channels for an RGB image)... adding a channel dimension to your input should help in that case...
you could append that channel dimension using either 

`spectrogram = spectrogram.reshape(spectrogram.shape + (1,))`
or
`spectrogram = np.expand_dims(spectrogram, -1)`

Comment: yeah, I think that is the solution also, but when I try both give this ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 129, 1071, 1), found shape=(None, 1071)

Comment: well, at prediction, the shape of the data add a 1, but gets rid of the number 129 and give me the same error

Comment: You still need to wrap spectrogram in a batch, thus you still need to use predict([spectrogram]), otherwise it will use 129 as batch dimension and thus remove it in the error message

Comment: what do you mean about wrap the spectrogram in a batch

Comment: look at the original answer i posted: wrap `spectrogram` in square brackets: 
`frecuencies, times, spectogram = signal.spectrogram(data, samplerate)`
`spectrogram = [spectrogram.reshape(spectrogram.shape + (1,))]`
`vc_prediction = voice_model.predict(spectogram)[0]`

Comment: yes, thats the problem, I do that but it still getting rid of the 129 and throwing the error:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240968/discussion-between-babrs-and-bernardo-olisan).